# SP - Get items form certain SPChoiceField

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, asp.net, dropdown, spfield

I need to get all items from SPChoiceField and insert in dropDownList ?

This is my code to get from everyone ChoiceField, I need to get **only from SPChoiceField with name "Company"**

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
                {
                    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList wayList = web.Lists["WayBill"];

                        foreach (SPField field in wayList.Fields)
                        {
                            //check whether field type is multi choice or not
                            if (field.Type == SPFieldType.Choice)
                            {
                                SPFieldChoice choice = (SPFieldChoice)field;
                                foreach (string choiceName in choice.Choices)
                                {
                                    ddCompany.Items.Add(choiceName);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**How to do this ?**

Answer (score 1):

**This is the solution (:**

```
SPList wayList = web.Lists["WayBill"];

     SPFieldChoice dropdown = wayList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Company") as SPFieldChoice;

     foreach (string choiceName in dropdown .Choices)
      {
         ddCompany.Items.Add(choiceName);
      }
```